# Join Field (Data Management)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins

I have two tables. One was created in excel, Table1, the other is an attribute table associated with a shapefile, Table2.

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

I want to join Table1 and Table2 into a single table, using the day of the year. When I try and run the "Join Field" tool, Table3 contains all the information from Table1, but Table2's time values have all been changed to midnight. When I perform a temporary join, it works just fine. I tried turning Table1's 'Date' from a string to a date, so it would match Table2, but it didn't fix anything.[image: Table3]

Comment: If you export the shapefile that contains the temporary join result, are all the times still midnight?

Comment: Yes. I tried that and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried converting the Excel table to dbf directly?  If that worked you could run the join with the dbf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date fields in Shapefiles (and DBF) do not store time, only dates.  From [Fundamentals of date fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm#GUID-395F7673-2D8F-442C-8912-C5E92204F1BB):

> *for coverages and shapefiles, the time portion is truncated from the
>   datetime value. For example, the datetime 2002-08-20 12:00:00 PM is
>   stored in a coverage or shapefile as 2002-08-20.*

If you want to store the time you'll need to convert to text first, or store the output in a File Geodatabase table or feature class.